# Matching pattern with optional nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query which tries to capture nodes in a certain order:

```
 A:genus-->B:family-->C:order-->D:class-->E:phylum
```

with labels `genus`, `family`, `order`, `class`, `phylum` and get a return similar to the table below.

Each of the nodes A:E have other properties
However in reality, nodes may be linked in the following manner

```
A:genus --> B:no_rank --> C:family --> D:class --> E:no_rank --> F:phylum
```

How do i capture such a structure where the pattern may miss a label or have additional nodes in between with a single query.

Currently my cypher query looks like this:

```
start basetaxa=node:ncbitaxid('taxid:2006379') 
match basetaxa-[:childof*0..]->(genus:`genus`)-[:childof*0..]->(family:`family`)-[:childof*0..]->(order:`order`)-[:childof*0..]->(class:`class`)-[:childof*0..]->(phylum:`phylum`) 
return genus.taxid,family.taxid,order.taxid,class.taxid,phylum.taxid;
```

which returns something like this

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| genus.taxid | family.taxid | order.taxid | class.taxid | phylum.taxid |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 914         | 206379       | 32003       | 28216       | 1224         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row
```

Comment: Are you always wanting to go from :genus to :phylum? And do you only want the `taxid` property from the :genus, :family, :order, :class, and :phylum nodes or would you want all `taxid` properties from all nodes between :genus and :phylum? You should also add your neo4j version to the question.

Comment: @NicoleWhite I'm trying to get the `taxid` of nodes with the labels `genus`, `family`, `order`, `class`, `phylum` which are connected to `basetaxa` in a unidirectional order.

Comment: Wonder if this works. 
START basetaxa=node:ncbitaxid('taxid:914') 
MATCH basetaxa-[:childof*0..]->(higher) 
WHERE higher:genus OR higher:family OR higher:order OR higher:class OR higher:phylum 
RETURN labels(higher), higher.taxid;

Comment: Should work, it only quickly checks the label on the node-record.